# Bash script not installing python packages properly

Tags: bash, openacc

I've been following this tutorial to install openacc locally on my jetson tk1 and I'm finding the install script to be incorrect. I didn't see any errors when I compiled the openacc library, however when I attempt to compile I get an error that says

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~/apps/acc/accull/yacf/examples/acc$ accull -v -o gpu.x  acc_test.c 
 **************************************** 
                 _    _ _      _          
                | |  | | |    | |         
   __ _  ___ ___| |  | | |    | |         
  / _` |/ __/ __| |  | | |    | |         
 | (_| | (_| (__| |__| | |____| |____     
  \__,_|\___\___|\____/|______|______|    
 **************************************** 
 Release 0.4alpha 

* Verbose output
* Output executable name gpu.x
* Processing acc_test.c to ./accull_k3Ty8/acc_test.c
* Building acc_test.c
* Running StS translation 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/acc/accull/yacf//bin/c2frangollo.py", line 64, in <module>
    from Backends.Frangollo.Mutators.Common import FrangolloMutatorError
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/acc/accull/yacf/Backends/Frangollo/Mutators/Common.py", line 33, in <module>
    from Backends.C99.Visitors.LlcFilters import AccScopeReverse, AccScopeFilter
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/acc/accull/yacf/Backends/C99/Visitors/LlcFilters.py", line 40, in <module>
    from Tools.Tree import NodeNotFound
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/acc/accull/yacf/Tools/Tree.py", line 34, in <module>
    c_ast = getCurrentLanguageAst()
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/acc/accull/yacf/Frontend/Shortcuts.py", line 40, in getCurrentLanguageAst
    myclass = __import__(config.FRONTEND_MODULE + '.' + str(name) + "." + str(name).lower() + '_ast', globals(), locals(), [str(name),])
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/acc/accull/yacf/Frontend/C99/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .c99_parser import C99Parser
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/acc/accull/yacf/Frontend/C99/c99_parser.py", line 15, in <module>
    import ply.yacc
ImportError: No module named ply.yacc
! Compilation of acc_test.c FAILED (no Project directory build )
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -Xcompiler -fopenmp -lrt -lcuda -lOpenCL -lrt -lcuda -arch=sm_20 *.o /home/ubuntu/apps/acc/accull/frangollo/src/libfrangollo.a -o gpu.x
nvlink fatal   : Could not open input file '*.o'
* Finished
```

http://scelementary.com/2015/04/30/openacc-on-jetson-tk1.html

```
#!/bin/bash

ACCULLROOT=/home/ubuntu/apps/acc

mkdir -p $ACCULLROOT/source
cd $ACCULLROOT/source

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tar.xz
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Sphinx/Sphinx-1.3.1.tar.gz
wget http://lxml.de/files/lxml-3.4.2.tgz
wget http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply-3.4.tar.gz
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/Mako/Mako-1.0.1.tar.gz

tar xvf Python-2.7.9.tar.xz
cd Python-2.7.9/
./configure --prefix=$ACCULLROOT
make -j2 
make install

list=(Sphinx-1.3.1.tar.gz lxml-3.4.2.tgz ply-3.4.tar.gz Mako-1.0.1.tar.gz)
for file in $list
do
  if [ "$file" == "*.tgz" ] 
    name=$(basename $file .tgz)
  then
    name=$(basename $file .tar.gz)
  fi

  tar zxvf $file
  cd $basename
  $ACCULLROOT/bin/python setup.py build
  $ACCULLROOT/bin/python setup.py install
  cd ..

done
```

Comment: You might have to run the script as root/sudo. You could also try to install `ply` manually. `pip install ply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

- You initialize an array called `list` but you attempt to iterate over its elements like this `for file in $list` which will only iterate over the first element, since `$list` is like `${list[0]}`.
  Use `for file in "${list[@]}"` to iterate over the complete array.
- Don't forget to double-quote your expansions to prevent [Globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) and [WordSplitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).
  For example `name=$(basename $file .tar.gz)` or `tar zxvf $file` will yield unwanted results in case the the value of the variable `file` contains white-spaces and is left without double-quotes ( i.e. `$file` instead of the correct form: `"$file"` )
- I guess that you mistakenly used `cd $basename` instead of `cd "$name"` - or something else, if it doesnt make sense. Anyhow the variable `name` appears to be unused.
- This line `[ "$file" == "*.tgz" ]` is probably wrong. It seems that the writer is attempting to match `"$file"` against a *glob* pattern. Well, in order to do that, two things must change: 1. Use `[[` instead of `[`, since the command `[` simply does not support *glob* matching. 2. The double-quotes around *.tgz should be removed - otherwise, `"$file"` will be matched against a literal `*.tgz`. So to summarize 1 and 2, the script should use `[[ $file = *.tgz ]]` instead of `[ "$file" == "*.tgz" ]`. I encourage you to read further about [TestsAndConditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) and to see this great [FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031), which is a part of this [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) - probably one of the best ( if not the only ) source to learn Bash from.
- The script does not check whether `cd` exited successfully, and simply continues on. It can give unwanted results. `cd || exit` is prefered, but modify it to be descriptive to the user.
- Regarding the variable `ACCULLROOT` : By convention, environment variables (`PATH`, `EDITOR`, `SHELL`, ...) and internal shell variables (`BASH_VERSION`, `RANDOM`, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since 
              variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Comment: I didn't see this before and I've seen found an alternative to openacc but thank you for this detailed reply!